# Buttons and input field is not coming in one row

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

### I want to create choose file options like this :-

### | Choose File      |Browse_btn| |Upload_btn| |Cancel|

I am writing that code in html but i am not getting this output.

***Html Code :-***

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5" style="margin-right :20px; border: 1px solid #e5e5e5; height: 32px; margin-right: 40px;">
      <div style="height: 32px;">
        <input type="file" name="fileupload" value="fileupload" id="fileupload" style=" margin-right: 80px;" class="mt-3" />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" onclick="fnUpload()" class="btn blue">
        <input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="cancelUpload()" class="btn blue">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what exactly you want.

```
<html>
 <head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" 
     href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"> 
   </script>
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"> 
   </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5" style="margin-right :20px; border: 1px solid #e5e5e5; height: 32px; margin-right: 40px;">
      <div style="height: 32px;">
        <span> Choose File : </span>
        <input type="button" id="loadFileXml" value="Browse" onclick="document.getElementById('file').click();" />
        <input type="file" style="display:none;" id="file" name="file"/>
       <input type="submit" value="Upload" onclick="fnUpload()" class="btn blue" style="display:inline-block">
       <input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="cancelUpload()" class="btn blue" style="display:inline-block">
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Working example : https://codepen.io/pgurav/pen/mddKPmY

Answer (score 2):

Try add display: flex; in following line.

```
<div style="height: 32px;display: flex;">
....
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
display: flex;
```

to the inner div with the 32px height style

Answer (score 1):

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5" style="margin-right: 40px; display:flex">

        <input type="file" name="fileupload" value="fileupload" id="fileupload" class="mt-3" />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" onclick="fnUpload()" class="btn blue">
        <input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="cancelUpload()" class="btn blue">

    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your question is tagged bootstrap-4 but you are importing version 3:

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

You can use an `input-group` in Bootstrap 4 to show the buttons like you want to.
Refer to the [official documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/input-group/#custom-file-input) if you want to customize more.

The code will eventually look something like this:

```html
<html>        
<head>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
    
<body>
      <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
                <div class="input-group" style="margin-right :20px; border: 1px solid #e5e5e5; height: 32px; margin-right: 40px;">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <span class="input-group-text">Choose file</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="custom-file">
                        <input type="file" name="fileupload" value="fileupload" id="fileupload" style=" margin-right: 80px;" class="mt-3" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        <input type="submit" value="Upload" onclick="fnUpload()" class="btn blue">
                        <input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="cancelUpload()" class="btn blue">
                    </div>
                </div>
           </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set float left on #fileupload like so:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

 <style>
     #fileupload { float:left; }
 </style>
<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5" style="margin-right :20px; border: 1px solid #e5e5e5; height: 32px; margin-right: 40px;">
      <div style="height: 32px;">
        <input type="file" name="fileupload" value="fileupload" id="fileupload" style=" margin-right: 80px;" class="mt-3" />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" onclick="fnUpload()" class="btn blue">
        <input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="cancelUpload()" class="btn blue">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```